# How to use mod_rewrite on OS X

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use mac os x 10.6.8 and I have a problem with mod_rewrite - it dosent work.

I changed *AllowOverride All* in `/etc/apache2/users/my_user.conf` and `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

.htaccess Code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

PHP:

```
var_dump($_GET['q']);
```

Result:

```
Trying: http://localhost/~nonamez123/konkurs/asgfsddsh  

Not Found

The requested URL /Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/index.php was not found on this server.
```

as you can see, rewrite on `index.php` going on, but the `index.php` can not be found

Logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2012:21:06:13 +0300] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009d64a8/initial] (3) [perdir
/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/] strip per-dir prefix:
/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/asfdasdf -    asfdasdf
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2012:21:06:13 +0300] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009d64a8/initial] (3) [perdir
/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri
'asfdasdf'
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2012:21:06:13 +0300] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009d64a8/initial] (4) [perdir
/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/] RewriteCond:
input='/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/asfdasdf' pattern='!-f' =>
matched
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2012:21:06:13 +0300] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009d64a8/initial] (4) [perdir
/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/] RewriteCond:
input='/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/asfdasdf' pattern='!-d' =>
matched
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2012:21:06:13 +0300] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009d64a8/initial] (2) [perdir
/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/] rewrite 'asfdasdf' ->
'index.php?q=asfdasdf'
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2012:21:06:13 +0300] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009d64a8/initial] (3) split
uri=index.php?q=asfdasdf -    uri=index.php, args=q=asfdasdf
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2012:21:06:13 +0300] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009d64a8/initial] (3) [perdir
/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php ->
/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2012:21:06:13 +0300] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009d64a8/initial] (1) [perdir
/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/] internal redirect with
/Users/nonamez123/Sites/konkurs/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your development files in ~user/Sites, I would put them in the webserver root, which is in /Library/WebServer/Documents. I've had better luck with that.

Then, make sure that your AllowOverride All in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf is inside the directory tag marked `<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">`. There are several AllowOverride directives in httpd.conf, the one you want to modify is around line 217ish if you use my approach.

Also make sure that the line `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so` is uncommented.

Finally make sure you restart apache with `sudo apachectl graceful`.

If you do want to use your user sites directory, this blog entry has some tips.
http://johnattebury.com/blog/2012/07/upgrading-to-mountain-lion-forbidden-403-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-username-on-this-server/